# What does _top in the hyperlink target do?

Tags: html

I sometimes see `target="_top"` in an anchor tag. What does it do?

```
<a href="http://foobar.com" target="_top">Foobar</a>
```

Answer (score 49):

> target=:
>
> `_top`: Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
>
> `_blank`:     Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
>
> `_self`:  Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was
> clicked (this is default)
>
> `_parent`:    Opens the linked document in the parent frame
>
> `framename`:  Opens the linked document in a named frame

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 47):

If the link is in an `iframe`, the new webpage will not be loaded in the `iframe` but instead the browser will open the page in the window itself

Comment: Tidbit: As a security measure, browsers won't let an iframe from a different domain change the _top location.  Instead a new tab will open (or nothing at all).

Answer (score 19):

It's a [browsing context](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#context) name.

> A valid browsing context name or keyword is any string that is either
>   a valid browsing context name or that is an ASCII case-insensitive
>   match for one of: _blank, _self, _parent, or _top.

Take a look at the matrix [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword), which describes the behavior of the `target` attribute in different scenarios.

The practical effect is that `_top` references the topmost window (technically [the top level browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context)).

`<a href="http://foo.com" target="_top">a link</a>` tells the browser to navigate to "foo.com" not in its own frame, but in the topmost frame. If the current frame *is* the topmost frame, the URL will open in the same window.

See also: [Browsing Contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#windows) (if you're in the mood for some deep reading).

Answer (score 5):

`target="_top"` will open the link at the top level of all defined framesets.

Answer (score 1):

as @hamon [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230959/what-does-top-in-the-hyperlink-target-do/16230994#16230994)

**Example to use _top with jQuery**

If your site is **contained in a frameset**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(top.location != location) {
        $('a, form').each(function() {
            if(!this.target) {
                this.target = '_top';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So.. All links in your site gonna open in **new window** *not in the frame* [(Credit)](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-target-links-top/)

Answer (score 1):

`target="_top"` attribute causes the "target" of the hyperlink to display at the top level of all currently defined framesets. It opens the linked document in the full body of the window

From : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp