# sms: and mailto: failure on iPhone Safari Mobile Browser

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links

## Problem:

Web page with sms: and mailto: links fail on ios mobile safari browser. A click on the link redirects you to:

> Safari cannot open the page because it cannot redirect to locations
> starting with "sms:"

or

> Safari cannot open the page because it cannot redirect to locations
> starting with "mailto:"

These used to work just fine up until around two or three months ago.  Now these fail on Apple mobile devices using the Safari browser.

## Background:

- I create responsive web pages for activity based teams.  One of the things we do is provide a team roster.  The roster includes links for telephone numbers, SMS text pages and Email.
- To keep things simple, we are using simple web pages.
- Because of security and privacy concerns, this content is only served via ajax call via node.js server after login. We're using a single node.js Express server to host the website content and manage http/api calls.
- Generally a click on the link pushes the mobile device into the appropriate native app for a phone call, SMS text message or email.
- This has been working great for a couple of years, on all devices.
- Lately we're seeing the problem on iPhones... but...
- Here's the really weird part.  I've got three teams using this technique..  The failure is only on TWO of the three teams.  SMS link works just fine there.
- The "tel:" link works fine on all devices.
- The failures only occur on two of the three sites for sms: and mailto: on the iphone. Things still work just fine on Android devices, on Windows and on MacOS.  The problem is Apple mobile devices.
- The two sites that have the failures are Progressive Web Apps, with a manifest.json file and service_worker.js.  The site that works fine has neither of those. When I remove the manifest, and turn off the service worker there is no improvement.
- All three sites hosted via App engine at Google Cloud.  The two sites that fail are only using web_app.appspot.com addressing.  The site that functions well is using a real URL, pointing to the app engine location.

## Typical Code:

```
<li>
    <div class="userName">Jane Doe</div>
    <div class="phoneNumber"><a href="tel:+1321-555-1234">321-555-1234</a></div>
    <div class="sms"><a href="sms:+1321-555-1234"><img src="../images/crosstxt-icon.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="email"><a href="mailto:jane.doe@yahoo.com"><img src="../images/email-icon.png"></a></div>
</li>
```

I wonder if this will show the issue, if you open this up in the browser of your Apple mobile device:

```html
<a href="sms:+1321-555-1234">Click here to create a SMS message.</a>
<br>
<a href="mailto:jane.doe@not_a_real_email_service.com">Click here to create an email message.</a>
```

Apparently that's a fail. You don't even get to see the run snippet button on my mobile device.

Comment: Hmm,  not sure what is up with your code or the snippet editor here, but [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto) works for both mail and sms on iPad and iPhone

Comment: Wow.  I tried on that editor a simple `href="sms:...` link without the `target="_top"` addition.  No go your tryit tool.  Both sms and email links worked great at that site, but only with  `target="_top"`    I tried adding that to my existing online site, and it's a fail.  I confirmed the correct code addition via Safari Remote Inspector on iphone. Not sure what is going on.  Still seeing the `cannot open page` errors.  Thx for sharing the info on `target=...` stuff.   [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230959/what-does-top-in-the-hyperlink-target-do)

Comment: See things I've tried here - hates web app mode... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256976/opening-new-sms-on-ios-in-web-app-mode-with-html5-link-from-within-bootstrap-pop

Answer (score 1):

#### Testing, more testing...

I just figured out... if I save the site to my mobile device homepage, such that an icon is added to home screen and in display mode, you can NOT see the top URL address bar, nor the Safari options bar on the bottom then the SMS: will fail.  If you just open the address in Safari, but don't save the file, then it will work great.

Again, when I'm in [Apple Web Application mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), the SMS link fails.

One hack... open the site via Safari mobile browser on the iphone.  Save the site to Home Page.  Verify the Icon is on the mobile phone.  Go to Settings --> Safari --> Advanced --> Website Data, then Delete the site by sliding the content left.  Cache storage is clean, but the Icon remains on the mobile screen.  Use the Icon to aid in login, but don't save the site again.  Note the URL line is visible.  SMS will work.

Still testing here... 
I tried to build a simple example to show the issue.  I was totally unable to get the sample to fail with the error messages above.  For reference the test site is [here.](https://zipzit.github.io/sms_link_test/)   The test source code is [here.](https://github.com/zipzit/zipzit.github.io/tree/master/sms_link_test)

I'm suspecting that the issue revolves around the fact that the two sites in question are both located at a subdomain site. (mywebapp.appspot.com) When the manifest includes all "valid" content the site does appear as a ios Apple Web app without visible URL line... but whenever I'm in that mode, SMS links are a total fail.

With that said, you can control the storage mode via  `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` .

During my testing, I also noticed that whenever the manifest.json file contains `//` comment marks anywhere the file is ignored by Safari.  Normally `//` comments are not allowed in a .json file, but according the [MSN source,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) they are fine in a manifest.json file.

The choice is

- a bit ugly and functional, or
- pretty and non-functional

Currently I'm running `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">`... I get the advantage of a custom icon on the home screen, even though the web app is still obviously inside a mobile browser with top/bottom info lines visible, sigh.

Comment: I've seen the same issue, and can confirm that:

1. when the web app is saved to the home screen, `sms:` links dont work.
2. the same web app opened in mobile safari using the address bar, `sms:` links work.

I will try the meta tag you describe and see if that works