# URL issue with an iframe

Tags: wordpress, url, iframe, hyperlink

I have integrated an iframe (a 3D menu to be precise) in a WordPress website without building my own theme. So I have just put an iframe on the previous page with my html code with the integrated iframe.
My problem is the following : when I click on a menu tab, it goes on the well page but the link doesn't change and I can see the 3D under the content of the tab...

Anyone has an idea ? I searched in the ftp files but nothing worked...
To note, the url work when I use the "target=_blank" and the tabs are opening in the new window (but I want the tab to be on the same window and I already tried target=_self --> doesn't work)

Thank you.

I tried to change links in the ftp files but without result.

Comment: When your user generates an event (like a click) in an iframe and you want the event to be handled in the containing frame, you must use Javascript's [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method to send the event from the iframe. That's a bit complex and is the reason why most people don't put menus in iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `target=_top` to get the URLs to open in the same window, but at the top level of the page rather than in the iFrame.

See [What does _top in the hyperlink target do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230959/what-does-top-in-the-hyperlink-target-do)